# Channel or email to report a security bug?

Tags: python

I recently identified a security vulnerability on one of Blender's subdomains and would like to report it to the appropriate team. Could you please provide me with the proper channel or email address for reporting security bugs?

Thanks in advance and lets keep the security and integrity of Blender's presence.

Comment: No-one here works for or has any association with the Blender Foundation and there are quite a few Blender websites with different web addresses so you're on your on there.

Comment: just search for github + blender, there you can open issues

Answer (score 1):

Bur reports generally go to the [official bug tracker](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues), however as stated in the report page, security vulnerabilities should be reported privately.

See the [Blender Wiki about Security Vulnerabilities](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Vulnerability_Reports)

> Security issues should be reported to `{security[at]blender.org}`. The security team will typically get back to vulnerability reporters within several days.